# Please explain how to Stack Overflow because I do not get it

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, users, post-ban

Apparently I can no longer add answers, and I can not post comments (<50 points). I basically can't do anything to dig me out of the hole unless asking stupid questions I already know the answer to?

How is this going to work out? I have studied Business Informatics and been coding since 1999 (started with HTML scripting). So I know some stuff and am able to help users on a wide variety of topics ([Tcl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl), PHP, CSS, HTML, MSL, [ABAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABAP), Java, JavaScript, etc.). It would be nice if I could at least add comments.

Solution to my problem:

[image: Three-step program to resolving ban issues]

Just click your account on the top, go to answers and look at what you answered. Then edit whatever you can to provide a real answer. That made the trick for me, at least. GL&HF!

Comment: You could go onto meta to ask this. Good luck. -1

Comment: Have you tried taking the tour of the site yet? - http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: If *you* deleted your poor answers, you should undelete and improve them. Deleted posts work against you for the purposes of the q- and a-bans.

Comment: Your code has no context here.  I'm not entirely sure why you posted it. As for your answer ban, [read this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/175248).

Comment: Did you delete your answers?  Or did someone else (a mod or several members of the community)?  That could hint at how off-topic your deleted answers were.

Comment: I did never delete anything on here. See my post to the answer below, please.

Thanks for the Tour link, did not see this before!

Comment: Btw. the most frustrating thing about this is that I have a problem that is being "dealt" with here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482219/jquery-animation-is-slower-and-lags-in-chrome-on-server-side (and others because this is a very common problem it seems).
But I can not contribute to solving this, which I really need for my website to work brilliantly (right now I deactived scrolling background images in both ff and chrome and only use them in IE9+ (which is basically a joke to any webdeveloper)).

Comment: So I am basically left with one of three decisions:
1. Open a new question where I can interact with people (not at all a good idea)
2. do nothing
3. Make a new account and answer without an answer but rather more questions
---(Comment spam, because too few characters (in case I am getting banned or downvoted even more))

Comment: Joachim, the linked duplicate answers your questions. Quickly: your best bet is to ask good questions. Enough of those, and the ban will probably be lifted. Also potentially helpful: suggesting edits to improve others' existing questions and answers.

Comment: I have TWO questions, that are brilliant but no one can answer them and I can not continue my work if those will not be fixed as they are essential for my site to work.
So instead of running to the next building yard I really want to interact to solve these, first.

Comment: General hint for success in life: *proclaiming your own magnificence is not a way to make friends*. Really.

Comment: @Joachim I can only see one questions in your profile.  If you have a question then ask it (showing what you tried and making them clear) let us worry about if we can answer it

Comment: So I am allowed to make a new post of an existing question if it has not yet been answered? I really do not want to get more bans, so I am only doing this if it obliges the SOF rules.

Comment: You have 3 deleted answers in the past: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967130/mysql-select-one-column-distinct-with-corresponding-other-columns/17975612#17975612 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348980/facebook-send-dialog-adding-a-linebreak-in-the-description/16672826#16672826 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805741/jscrollpane-not-working-with-twitter-profile-feed/15473143#15473143. None of those were answers to the question. You have one old deleted question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975702/ie9-crashes-because-of-hover-navigation which wasn't a question

Comment: Your most recent question wasn't a question either.

Comment: No, such a duplicate will be closed, if its duplicity is discovered. But you can edit your existing question to improve it, if you like.

Comment: @dmckee: I am not here to make friends. I am here to discuss the evolution of the web on a basis of bringing it to the next level. And sorry, but my questions are brilliant because they are definetely flaws in both the FB Api and Chrome / Firefox, that need to be fixed by their authors. No harm meant to anyone. The more attention it gets, the faster it will be dealt with (at least I hope so).

Comment: @Joachim if your question is exactly the same as an existing question then no, you shouldn't reask it. But you csn suggest an edit to it to clarify it if it isn't very well written (unclear,  misspellings etc)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352190/facebook-api-post-how-to-get-larger-thumbnail?noredirect=1#comment28682532_19352190
How do I make this better / more transparent? I have no clue, sorry.

Comment: @joachim reporting bugs/problems is off topic, best to report it to the authors of said libraries. Additional all discussions are also off topic. We want questions and answers, not discussions

Comment: @Flexo:  "First ask, then supply your own answer and accept it. So 1.) Create the question, 2.) Answer it yourself, 3.) Accept your own answer, 4.) Done! –  Markus Hofmann Jul 31 at 16:24"
Is this supposed to be a joke? I provided the solution right away, which is far superior to ask first and then drop the answer in 2 minutes later. But hey, I can cheat, too.

Comment: If you are here to "discuss" then you are in the wrong place. Stack Overflow is different from the hordes of "forums" around the internet and if you keep ignoring that you will only encounter more frustration. On the other hand, if you care to learn how we do things here and participate *within* that culture you may find it to be very rewarding.

Comment: So basically the consense is to cheat your way up to reputation by asking questions that not yet have been asked and answering these instantly to abide the rules of the system.

Hey, I can do that, no problem.

Comment: You're frustrated, Joachim, and broadcasting that frustration with an incandescent intensity. Nothing productive is being achieved here. I really suggest stepping away for a little while.

Comment: @dmckee: So discussing your own answers with yourself is obliged, but discussion on substant matters are not?

Maybe the system needs a change or two?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta How is that a helpful comment / answer / info / text in terms of the rules of SOF? Please, explain.

Comment: *" Maybe the system needs a change or two? "* This system has resulted in Stack Overflow growing to be the largest programming help site on the internet. I think we're pretty happy with it.

Comment: I have asked and answered several of my own questions because I though it would help other people, but ok, I realise now I was just cheating

Comment: So now I have changed all the illegal questions / comments, but I can not do anything about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975702/ie9-crashes-because-of-hover-navigation
It is deleted by an admin and the edit button is grayed out. So now I will start asking questions and solve them later feeling a bit like a turtle in hamster’s wheel.

Still thanks for explaining things to each and everyone of you.

Comment: I've undeleted two answers which look to be fixed. I've left one though - it seems to be an exact duplicate of an older answer with just a comment added. Either way this was enough to tip you back to unbanned again - happy answering, make them count!

Comment: @Flexo I tried to use a common syntax "<tableName>"  (SOF just deleted the word, though (probably because of HTML syntax)) to declare that the tableName needs to be edited by the user and I added the missing ; and switched it to better ' instead of ´ which are apostrophs. Also I corrected a mistake where the column name was not written correctly (firstname -> FirstName). So I basically enhanced the answer by 4 ways, so it would be nice if not just counted as copying.

But thanks anyways for unbanning! Great.

Comment: How come I can not answer this question? There’s just no button / textbox.

Comment: This question here on meta? It's marked as a duplicate which means it's unanswerable.

Comment: What is MSL (second paragraph)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen mIRC scripting language

Answer (score 9):

### How to use Stack Exchange

If you have something you've tried and got stuck with;

- Ask a question

If you see a question you can answer;

- Answer it.

Neither of these require reputation and are the primary activities on the site.

### Moving forward from an answer ban

It sounds however like you've been answer banned (presumably by posting things that aren't answers as answers). You can lift this by improving your existing answers and getting upvotes or contributing positively in other ways.

All your existing answers appear to be deleted so if you think you *can* make real answers out of them you can flag and ask a moderator to undelete them. Or you can contribute positively by posting quality questions or making helpful edits.

Comment: Yes, I used answer to comment on something because I could not give the answer without getting more information first. It seems to me that this was wrong, but how else do I get 50 points. It is not that easy to come up with the perfect answer to a post that is like "my script does not work."?!

Comment: @Joachim True, but generally someone else will ask in a comment.  Or just move on, most questions can be answered without more information (or people demand the extra information pretty quickly). I remember it being a bit frustrating too, but it's considered necessary to break people from the forum mentality

Comment: Sure thing, I totally get why it is there and all but now I can not do ANYTHING. All my questions seem to be too far out of anyone’s business (FB Api call for example) and I can NOT answer, nor comment, nor do anything else.

So this account is crashed? Make a new one or ask the staff? How do I even get hold of an Admin? Aren’t they supposed to read stuff likes this from time to time, anyway?

Btw. thanks for your help! Really appreciate it, as I do like the site and its users.

Comment: @Joachim it is difficult, you can contact the stack exchange team with the [contact us](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) link, but I can't promise you'll get an answer you like. Do you think you could convert your comment answers to real answers?

Comment: Related; I proposed this to help warn people more with this; [Warn a user on answering a question after they've had a question deleted as not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211450/after-an-answer-is-deleted-as-not-an-answer-give-a-timed-message-box-before-po)

Comment: I hope I can edit them, I am not really sure I am allowed to view the site anymore in 5 minutes.

Comment: I doubt suggested edits have any effect on ban or getting unbanned. No harm will come of course, but chances are small that it will help getting out of a post ban. +1 anyway for the good answer!

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't know about suggested edits (algorithm being secret and all that) but I did talk to one user who got unbanned purely from unrelated positive contribution (good questions and edits with an answer ban) whether it was just the questions or if the edits helped too I don't know

Comment: @shadowWizard here is the link to what I was talking about; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212896/how-can-i-get-out-of-an-answer-ban-faq-inadequate/212897#comment685476_212896

Comment: Nice, but I still believe it's only the upvotes on answers that got him out of the ban. :)